# Standard web services v Secure web services

Tags: web-services, ws-security

I ask this question in anticipation as part of a project. I have experience of developing and consuming web services in the past and am au fait with those. However I have been told that as part of this next project I will need to use "secure" web services. Can you provide some insight into what additional development tasks there will be to implement these as opposed to standard dare i say it insecure web services?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have a complex multi-hop scenario, then SSL is vastly more practical and interoperable than anything based on WS-Security or related specification

Answer (score 2):

If your going to be using WCF, check out these guide lines on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735093.aspx)

Exising ASMX Web Service can be secured using [Web Services Enhancements (WSE) 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms977317.aspx)